# Render pandas dataframe to HTML table with row seperators

Tags: python, html, pandas, data-processing

I render a pandas multi-index into an html table.

When rendering, after I passed a specific index X I want to add a separator line into the table. I can do this manually by editing the final html file:

```
/* .... Index X .... */
<tr>
                <td colspan="20" class="divider"><hr /></td>
</tr>
/* .... Index Y .... */
```

This produces the desired result:

[image].

**Question** Is there any way to capture this in code?
I want to avoid going through each HTML table I create, adding those lines manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` index and loop through it while adding the separator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":list("AABBCCA"),"unit":[1,2,1,3,4,4,6]})

for _, data in df.groupby("col1"):
    print (data.to_html())
    print ('<td colspan="20" class="divider"><hr /></td>')
```

Result:

[image]