# Pandas multiple Dataframes to HTML page with Headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add multiple Dataframes to a single HTML page with different Headers.

Currently, I am using `to_html` function to add multiple Dataframes in the HTML page.

Can anyone please help me to add multiple DFs in one page with ***line breaks*** and ***Headers*** like tags.

Thank You

Comment: What is your code? There is some loop?

Comment: You mean [adding row separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524944/render-pandas-dataframe-to-html-table-with-row-seperators/60525789#60525789)?

Comment: Here is my code,`with open("Res.html", 'w') as _file:
        _file.write(df1.to_html(border=5) +                     df2.to_html(index=False,border=5) + df3.to_html(na_rep="",border=5) +                     +df4.to_html(na_rep="",border=5)) `@jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not a very big problem, But it may help someone

Here is my code:

```
with open("Result.html", 'w') as _file:
    _file.write('<center>' 
                +'<h1> Main Heading </h1><br><hr>'
                +'<h2> Heading1 </h2>' + df1.to_html(index=False,border=2,justify="center") + '<be><hr>'
                +'<h2> Heading2 </h2>' + df2.to_html(index=False,border=2,justify="center") + '<br><hr>'
                +'<h2> Heading3 </h2>' + df3.to_html(index=False,border=2,justify="center") + '<br><hr>'
                +'</center>')
```